# How to do the redundancy of two servers that have firebird database and an ethernet communication application with 100 clients

Tags: windows, database

how to do the redundancy of two servers that have firebird database and an ethernet communication application with 10 clients.

We have two servers with system windows 2012, which run the same application that uses communication via socket with 80 equipment, these devices send several messages via a proprietary protocol for both servers.
But only one of these servers should send messages via SOAP to another system.
the System works but without redundancy of sending the messages to the third server via SOAP, since this server that receives these messages can receive only 1 server and not both.
How could this redundancy problem be solved?

OBs. depending on the project there may be up to 200 devices communicating as client sockets

Comment: 10 clients or 100?

Comment: may be up to 200 devices communicating as client sockets.

Comment: I was referring to your inconsistent text. Reread title and first sentence. Secondly, provide further detail as edits to the Question rather than as comments.